# -bash: cd: root: no such file or directory

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, root

I run these commands step by step:

```
rakinar2@hotspot:/$ ls -CF
bin@ boot/ cache/ dev/ d/ data/ etc/ home/ mount/ opt/ root/ sbin/ sys/ usr/
rakinar2@hotspot:/$ ls -hal root
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Jul 16 16:39 ./
drwxr-xr-x 13 root root 4.0K Jul 16 16:39 ../
rakinar2@hotspot:/$ cd root
-bash: cd: root: no such file or directory
```

How do I fix this error and go to the /root directory?

Comment: Only root can enter the directory `/root`, so you need to [switch to root user](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889413/how-to-switch-to-root-user-but-stay-in-the-same-directory).

Comment: @Artur But it is still the wrong error message then... Should show `Permission denied`

Comment: @ArRakin, which Ubuntu version?

Comment: Agreed - but I'm curious what gets displayed if he tries as root.

Comment: But it should show `Permission denied` for the second command already. I somehow think that OP is not on Ubuntu.... The directories do not match. No typical directories like `cdrom`, `media`, `proc`, `run`, `tmp`,`var`, etc.

Comment: @pLumo agreed - they [previously posted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1351819/bash-sh-command-not-found) that their system doesn't have a `/bin/sh` or `/bin/dash` among other discrepancies.

Comment: @pLumo Version Bionic

Comment: Somehow it seems you changed a lot of things in your system, also regarding your previous question. I doubt we can help you rather than recommend a reinstall.

Comment: @pLumo I am trying to reinstall a fresh version of ubuntu.

Comment: @pLumo Now the system works fine, thanks!